# How can I open folder in VS Code using a full path instead of point and clicking on icons?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I can Ctrl+P and paste the path to a file and open it. However, if I choose "open folder", I get a clunky "open folder" interface with icons and and OK button that I need to spend time navigating using point-and-click.

Is there an equivalent to Ctrl+P but for folders instead? I already have the full path to the folder in my clipboard; I really don't want to waste time looking through lists of icons and double clicking them.

Of course, I know that I can just open terminal and do "code path/to/folder", but that opens up a new window. I want to just do Ctrl+P but for folders, i.e. in an existing window, with the path instead of icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS Code preferences, navigate to Files > Simple Dialog, and check the box. This uses a simple file dialog, instead of the system file dialog. To open a file, use ctrl+o, and to open a folder, use ctrl+k ctrl+o. (This can be remapped).

This can also be enabled in `settings.json`:

```json
"files.simpleDialog.enable": true
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is just that using `code <path>` opens in a new window, then the solution is to use the `--reuse-window` flag. The flag's description:

> Force to open a file or folder in an already opened window.

Your system's default file explorer application probably has an input element at the top of its window where you can paste in a full path as well.

You can also switch to VS Code's simple file explorer UI instead of the system file explorer by setting `"files.simpleDialog.enable": true` in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). The setting's description:

> Enables the simple file dialog. The simple file dialog replaces the system file dialog when enabled.